# Getting error when installing Bugsnag 'Error: spawn npm ENOENT'

Tags: npm, expo, bugsnag

this is the first time I post here so apologies if I don't follow some rules or incorrect formatting.
I'm making an app using React Native and Expo and when I try to install bugsnag I get this error.

```
$ npx bugsnag-expo-cli init
√ @bugsnag/expo does not appear to be installed, do you want to install it? ... yes
√ If you want the latest version of @bugsnag/expo hit enter, otherwise type the version you want ... latest
√ Using yarn or npm? » npm
> Installing @bugsnag/expo with npm. This could take a while!

  Error: spawn npm ENOENT
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
      at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you attempting to run the `bugsnag-expo-cli` on Windows? The Expo CLI currently only supports MacOS and Linux:
https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/expo/#installation-and-configuration

As an alternative to the CLI, you can follow the manual integration guide:
https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/expo/manual-setup/

Comment: Thanks! Ill give it a try, didn't know it was for MacOS and Linux only, yes i'm on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, cleaning the cache solved the problem (MacOS)

```
npm cache clean --force
```